# DESC counters in Cassandra similar to KEYSPACE & TABLES?

Tags: cassandra, counter, cqlsh

Is this possible in Cassandra `CQLSH` or through DevCenter to identify & count all counters in my whole Cassandra keyspaces.

I can do the same to get all `KEYSPACES`

```
cassandra@cqlsh> desc KEYSPACES;
```

Above gives me list of all keyspaces present in Cassandra. Similar I can do to get Tables.

```
cassandra@cqlsh> desc TABLES;
```

but I want to find all counters, which will give me similar results as above `CQLs`??

Comment: Do you want to find all tables with counters, or what?

Comment: yes i want to get all tables, which are using counters, or specifically if I can find all counters only that will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no separate command for it (and couldn't be), but you can achieve needed functionality using `cqlsh` & scripting, like this:

```
cqlsh -e 'describe schema;'|grep -e '^CREATE TABLE'| \
    sed -e "s|^CREATE TABLE \(.*\) (.*$|\1|" | \
    while read TBL ; do 
      if cqlsh -e "describe $TBL;"|grep -i -e '\S counter' >| /dev/null; then
       echo "$TBL"
      fi
    done
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, your answer was helpful. ./cqlsh {hostname} 9042 -u {user_name} -p {password} -e 'describe schema;'|grep -e '^CREATE TABLE'| \
    sed -e "s|^CREATE TABLE \(.*\) (.*$|\1|" | \
    while read TBL ; do 
   echo "Checking table $TBL"
      if ./cqlsh {hostname} 9042 -u {user_name} -p {password} -e "describe $TBL;"|grep -i -e '\S counter' >| /dev/null; then
       echo "Found $TBL"
      fi
    done